# Create chart using data from mongodb

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, visualization

I need to generate different charts with d3.js using data from mongodb. Any people can advise on how to do it?? Never done something like this before

Visual analytic for traffic

Comment: Unfortunately your question is very vague. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.